How do I properly exit a program and return to the CCP in CP/M?
Once my CP/M program has finished doing whatever it's supposed to do, or the user chooses some sort of "quit" option, how do I return the user back to the CCP? Can I just do a ret? Or do I need to jump to some location or something like that?

Basically: Both. The programmer can decide whether they want to re-load the CCP after the program has finished or preserve it and simply return. Depends on your memory requirements:
You can perform a warm start by coding a
  rst  0      or
  jmp  0

(Both do the exact same thing, the jump just needs two bytes more memory).
This re-initializes the system and re-loads the transient part of the CCP (which obviously must be present on the logged-in disk). If you do that, you can consider the memory occupied by that transient part "yours" and use it for your program.
If you left the original stack intact that was present when your program was first executed, you can restore that stack pointer and simply return to the CCP
; end of program, return to CCP
LHLD OLDSP    ; restore initial stack pointer 
              ; (must have been saved before)
SPHL
RET           ; to the CCP

This spares the end user the inconvenience of waiting for a warm start (which normally really isn't that long) until the prompt comes back. It does, however, limit your program's available memory (not really significantly, but on CP/M, every byte might count), because you need to preserve the CCP's environment (code and stack) while your program is running.
Smaller utilities typically used the latter way, while bigger, memory-hungry programs used the first approach.
To find the lowest address occupied by the CCP, you would typically consult BDOS function 6 (if you want to preserve it) - I would assume most small utilities didn't even do that, but rather used trial and error to find out whether the CCP is still "alive" after they're done - or use the system's base address (at $0006) as your upper limit if you intend to use CCP memory for your program.
When a transient program is started, the stack pointer of the new program points to an 8-level stack created by the CCP, the current (topmost) entry holds the CCP return address - So, if you don't allocate your own stack, you can use up to six subroutine levels from that CCP memory (one should be left reserved to be able to do system calls from any subroutine) and return to the CCP.

Presumably very small utilities with that know they won't overflow the original stack or overwrite the CCP could simply just ret at the end of the program, then, right? How big and where is the stack that CP/M 2.2 gives to user programs, and where does the CCP start small (24K?) and "regular sized" (64K) CP/M systems?

Actually, CP/M doesn't "give" any stack to transient programs - They have to set it up themselves in the TPA. For small utilities, you might get away with re-using a few bytes from the CCP's stack, but it can't be a lot. All of DR example programs set up their own stack and so should yours. You have the choice of restoring the CCP stack and return as pointed out above, but that's it. Also, there isn't a "standard" memory size below CCP - There are a lot of 3PP CPPs, and resident utilities that go between BDOS/BIOS and the CCP, so there really is no rule of thumb. But 8-10k should really be OK

But generally, if you only use a few bytes of stack (CP/M does indeed guarantee 7 * 2 bytes and does guarantee that it won't use that stack in system calls) and your program is reasonably small, there shouldn't be problem doing that.

For the first part it might be useful to point out that RST 0 and JMP 0 execute both the same code as both jump to address 0 (as does PCHL with HL=0, have seen that as well). In addition the same is reached (usually) by pressing RESET as that also starts execution a 0. (might be complicated by computer structure). After all, it's the whole idea of using the reset vector to support recovery (warmstart) in as many situation as possible.

@Raffzahn I was actually assuming that anyone who can write CP/M programs would know that ;) I was also assuming that any such person would be aware that JMP 0 actually wastes memory ;)  And I don't quite agree with your last sentence: Of course RST 0 presents you with a guaranteed clean state, but at the cost of a disk access - That you can avoid by simply returning to the CCP. Well, if you're program makes a mess of the system, you're probably better off with a RST 0...

@tofro Possible manual page to add. Well, the question is asked about something well known to any CP/M programmer by someone who seems to have knowledge (and able to read), so it's setup for getting a wiki like answer :)) Also, the last one isn't about what one can do, but explaining the elegance of using RST 0 to always produce a stable system. Last, while there is a return address in the 32 bytes of CCP provided stack, RETurning is not recommended by DR.

@Raffzahn While we're nit-picking: No, a RST 0 isn't necessarily the same thing as pressing the RESET button - It does execute the same code, yes, but a hardware reset may do a lot more things than that (I'm assuming that's what your "(usually)" meant to say).

@Raffzahn Disagree with "not recommended by DR" - Some DR example programs do exactly that, and the manuals point out the preconditions you have to meet.

Just for the sake of completeness, calling / jumping to BDOS (0005h) with C containing zero will also do a warm restart.  Not that it was used a lot, since JMP 0 or RST 0 are only one instruction vs the two needed for the BDOS method.  Citation: https://www.seasip.info/Cpm/bdos.html

Jump to location 0: jp 0 or rst 0 in Z80 assembly language. I confirmed this under RunCPM Version 6.1.)
Further information on using CP/M APIs can be found in the CP/M 2.2 manual section 5, CP/M 2 System Interface. Among other things, it states:

The transient program is called from the CCP. Thus, it can simply return to the CCP upon completion of its processing, or can Jump to BOOT to pass control back to CP/M. In the first case, the transient program must not use memory above CBASE, while in the latter case, memory up through FBASE-1 can be used.
...
Upon entry to a transient program, the CCP leaves the stack pointer set to an eight-level stack area with the CCP return address pushed onto the stack, leaving seven levels before overflow occurs. Although this stack is usually not used by a transient program (most transients return to the CCP through a jump to location 0000H) it is large enough to make CP/M system calls because the FDOS switches to a local stack at system entry.

The CP/M memory map looks like this:

The start of the FDOS (BDOS+BIOS) is found in the word at location BOOT+$06, which is almost invariably just $06. There is no way to query the OS for the size of the CCP, but under CP/M 2 the CCP is a fixed size of $800 bytes. (This is fixed by the area allocated to it in the OS tracks by the system generation process. However, this does assume you are using the standard CCP or a replacement that follows the same conventions as the DR code. I don't know if things like ZCPR do this.)

Why not rst 0? It would save you a couple of bytes and the OS should tidy up the stack and whatever.

To add to the other answers, here's how the CP/M 2 Interface Guide describes the initial program environment:

Upon entry to a transient program, the CCP leaves the stack pointer set to an eight level stack area with the CCP return address pushed onto the stack, leaving seven levels before overflow occurs. Although this stack is usually not used by a transient program (i.e., most transients return to the CCP though a jump to location 0000H), it is sufficiently large to make CP/M system calls since the FDOS switches to a local stack at system entry. The following assembly language program segment, for example, reads characters continuously until an asterisk is encountered, at which time control returns to the CCP (assuming a standard CP/M system with BOOT = 0000H):

BDOS    EQU   0005H   ;STANDARD CP/M ENTRY
CONIN   EQU   1       ;CONSOLE INPUT FUNCTION
;
        ORG   0100H   ;BASE OF TPA
NEXTC:  MVI   C,CONIN ;READ NEXT CHARACTER
        CALL  BDOS    ;RETURN CHARACTER IN <A>
        CPI   '*'     ;END OF PROCESSING?
        JNZ   NEXTC   ;LOOP IF NOT
        RET           ;RETURN TO CCP
        END


As requested, here's the link to the documentation:
From the CP/M Plus Operating System Programmers Guide, p- 1-8:

Transient programs can terminate execution by jumping to location 0000H in the  Page Zero region. This location contains a jump instruction to BIOS base+3, which contains a jump instruction to the BIOS warm start routine. The BIOS warm start routine loads the CCP into memory at location 100H and then passes control to it.


This is very specific to CP/M 3.0. In 2.2, the CCP does not reside at the lower end of the TPA (but rather at the top end)

@tofro: I would have thought the most logical way to set up the CCP would have been to have it load at 100h, but when spawning another program copy itself to the top of memory and set the stack pointer to point just below it.  A program could test SP against its memory requirements, and either leave the stack pointer (and everything above it) alone, or set the stack pointer to top of memory and push zero.  In either case, the program could then exit by doing a RET with the stack at the top level.

@supercat In CP/M 2.x, the CCP is one piece and loaded just below the BDOS/BIOS at the top of the TPA. In CP/M 3.x, the CCP is significantly larger and consists of two pieces, one, the "resident" part lives just below the system like in 2.x, the other, "transient" part is loaded like a "normal" program into the lower TPA at $100. You can, of course, create your own application stack and push a zero address, then simply RETurn when your program terminates (which will then do the warm start dance). You should, however, not assume that SP points to the end of the TPA when your program starts.

... SP rather points into internal CCP storage.

In CP/M 2.x, you can "run" a program with 0 bytes, and it will just repeat running the last executed user program which still sits in the TPA. If you do the same thing in CP/M 3.0, you will simply re-start the CCP.

@tofro: How is a CP/M program supposed to decide whether there would be enough memory to leave CCP resident, if storage below SP can't be considered "fair game"?  Do other registers indicate top of memory with CCP resident and top of memory if CCP is jettisoned?

@supercat I wrote that in my answer: BDOS function 6 returns the bottom address of the CCP (i.e. the upper limit of usable TPA memory if you want to keep the CCP resident), ($0006) holds the bottom address of the system (i.e. the topmost address of the CCP + 1) if you intend to perform a warm start after your program terminates.

@tofro BDOS function 6 only returns the bottom address of the CCP in CP/M 1.3, not any later versions.

@john_e That's probably the reason why "most programs don't even check" and work based on trial and error.

@tofro: Having execution start with SP pointing to the top of storage that could be used while keeping CCP, another register holding the top of available memory if CCP was jettisoned, and another register holding an address just past the highest loaded byte, would seem like it would have been simpler for CCP and called program alike than having to use a function call that may or may not be supported, and reporting the size of the just-loaded program would allow an assembler or compiler to generate a COM file in a single pass by appending a "fix-up" list.

@supercat Note CP/M is far from what we would expect from an OS today - Once you have a look at the file handling support (you need to fill - and maintain - "File Control Block" structures instead of working with handles, for example), you'll really feel its age.

@tofro: Of course.  One thing I find a bit curious, though, about old microcomputer systems more generally is that there doesn't seem to have been an effort to have program loaders facilitate single-pass code generation for RAM-loaded programs.  It wouldn't be hard to design an 8080 assembler that could, given one pass through a source file on paper tape, punch a tape containing a blob that could be placed anywhere in memory with HL and DL pointing to the start and ending addresses, and invoked via JP (HL); some assembler-generated code at the start of the blob could then...

...build in memory a version of the program with all address fix-ups necessary to start at the address in HL.

@supercat You might want to have a look at RSX (resident system extensions) and GSX for CP/M - They more or less do that. Need to be fully relocatable, because they go between the system and the CCP. They use the CP/M .PRL format, which makes them load-time relocatable, are a bit of a rare beast, however. Amstrad developed something similar (.FID) for loadable drivers under CP/M 3.0.

@john_e: Address six will almost always hold the address of the CP/M code executed by a "CALL 5" instruction; what's uncertain is whether CP/M would put that code below everything else that must be left undisturbed.

@supercat The manuals actually guarantee that what's called when you call the system with a CALL 5 is the lowest address occupied by the system (I think even on the first page...)

@tofro, Yes, the manuals do guarantee that. I've linked to those sections in an update to my answer. I've also noted that you can determine the location of  the start of the CCP, at least if you're using the standard DR CCP, since it has a fixed maximum size.
